# VS express 2013 activation

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm a longtime user of 'Visual Studio express for WEB' (VS). Right now using VS 2013 express update 3.

Lately I changed my PC sytem i.e I reloaded Windows 8 and upgraded to 8.1 --> all is fine!

Via 'Microsoft Web Platform installer' I installed VS 2013 --> no Problem!
However, when starting VS2013 it says (immediately!) to register because the 30 day trial has expired.
PS: It immediately brings the login screen asking to access my MS account to register.
( ! I'm NOT able to access Help --> register screen to start the register process)

When providing my account ID / PW it's not accepted! ... However ....

When logging-in via 'login.live.com' and giving the very same ID / PW info I can access my account without any problems!

PS:
- since I registered my previous VS on my old machine I have changed my MS account!
- I'm NOT able to access that OLD account anymore!
- I acknowledge that I can't reconstruct everything I did when changing my MS account ...

? is there any other procedure to register!?

It seems to me that MS is - concerning my VS express - still using my old info to register!

Comment: I assume you have tried to install everything and install everything again

Comment: yes, I certainly un-installed and re-installed. No errors /msgs during install, all has completed ok. When providing the MS account info (ID/PW) I get error msg: 'SP324095: Our service was unable to complete the request.' .. I assume this is the MS account service!

Comment: well, after some days with trial and error I gave up; created a new MS account ... finally all is fine again!